# Drawing complex heat map in R

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to draw a using the heatmap.2 with dendrograms using hierarchical cluster analysis. However I need two write different methods for each of the dendrograms. For y axis, I need to write Ward's Method, distance binary. And my X axis, Ward method distance squared euclidean.

Does anyone have any idea how to write the code for this?

Comment: please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) cause I'm missing the parts where you add what tried and what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually specify the dendrograms like this:

```
library(gplots)
d1 <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mtcars, method = "euclidean"), method = "ward.D"))
d2 <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(mtcars), method = "euclidean"), method = "ward.D2"))
heatmap.2(as.matrix(mtcars), Rowv=d1, Colv=d2)
```

See also `?dist` and `?hclust` for more options concerning the distance measure and clustering method.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was a very neat way of coding for it!